# Is there an elegant way to separate Plugin Interface and Implementation in C#?

Tags: c#, plugins, interface

I am developing a C# desktop application that should try to find and consume a plugin hosted in a totally different C# project so that the application does not know anything of the plugin host project and its types.

If the plugin DLL is found in my application EXE folder, I should be able to create an instance of the plugin interface. But to do so in the application, I would need to make the plugin assembly known to the application solution at compilation time, which is not permissible due to the project management issues.

The only way to do it, as far as I can see, is to have two assemblies: the one with the interface only, which can be added to the application solution, and the other one with the plugin implementation.
But is there a possibly more elegant solution?

Comment: just search for matching assemblies, e.g. by their filename or just use all assemblies in your folder or whtaver. Than indicate if there's any class within those assemblies that implements the interface and if so create an instance of the implementing class using `Activator.CreateInstance`. Where **specifically** are you stuck here? Hard to indicate without seeing any code.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support

Comment: @HimBromBeere To the best of my knowledge, to instatiate a variable thru Activator you need to know its Type, not only the name. And to do so, you need an assembly in which the type resides.

Answer (score 2):

> The only way to do it, as far as I can see, is to have two assemblies: the one with the interface only, which can be added to the application solution, and the other one with the plugin implementation

This is the solution I have used for plugins. The interface project is hosted in the main application solution, with the interface dll either manually copied to the plugin solution, or referenced thru nuget. I'm not aware of any solution that is more elegant.

Changes to the interface will be slightly cumbersome, but this is not necessarily a bad thing since frequent changes to public APIs can be difficult for the user of the API. It is a good idea to have some plan for how different API versions should be handled by the plugin implementation. For example by exposing a version property in the interface that can be used to determine what methods are safe to call or not.

Comment: Thanks Jonas! Exact my case.

Comment: The version property is a great idea, BTW. Haven't thought of that!